# 100% height fill page only

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have 100% height but have the div fill out the entire page only.

So if i put 100% height on a div, it should extend the div all the way down to the end of the page but not extend anymore to bring any scroll bars. Is that possible? I know height:100% takes the page's height and puts the div's height to that number but I don't want the div to actually have the height of that number, but only extend till end of page, no more than that.

Is it possible with 100% height or anything else?

I appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want anyone to be able to scroll down further? If so, use `<div style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%;"></div>`

Comment: Isn't this default behavior? That is, wouldn't the page automatically resize to the maximum fixed vertical height?

Comment: This question has been solved, there is no correct answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
<div style="top:0;bottom:0,left:0,right:0;"></div>
```

or using jquery:

```
 $("#mydiv").height($(window).height());
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `padding` or `border`, if you declare the `html`, `body`, and `div` 100%, it will extend to the size of the browser window.

If you want to use `padding` and `border`, consider using the CSS3 property `box-sizing: border-box;`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AdSjQ/)

**Update:**

Using pseudo-elements (you could use an empty `div`):

```
.top{height:100px; width:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}
.rest{min-height:100%; background:lightblue; }
.rest:before{content:''; display:block; width:100%; height:100px;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aHA5j/)

Comment: Doesn't work. See over here:http://jsfiddle.net/AdSjQ/1/

See how the scroll bars appeared if there is another div on top. I don't want the div to extend down. I want it to continue to fill the bottom of the browser instead of expanding and bringing the scroll bars

Comment: Well, yes 100% + 100px is more than 100%.

Comment: Exactly, but I don't want that 100px added on, is there no way to keep the scroll bars from coming unless the content requires it?